# Extracting a number from a string using regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string:

```
fname="VDSKBLAG00120C02 (10).gif"
```

How can I extract the value `10` from the string `fname` (using `re`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
regex = re.compile(r"(?<=\()\d+(?=\))")
value = int(re.search(regex, fname).group(0))
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=\() # Assert that the previous character is a (
\d+     # Match one or more digits
(?=\))  # Assert that the next character is a )
```

Comment: Seems a bit overcomplicated. Why not just `\((\d+)\)`?

Comment: @DanielRoseman: Make a proper answer please. I prefer that solution too.

Comment: Using Daniels method: `int(re.compile(r"\((\d+)\)").search("VDSKBLAG00120C02 (10).gif").group(1))`

Comment: @DanielRoseman: I guess it's a matter of preference. This regex corresponds directly to the OP's requirements: "Match a number if it's surrounded by parentheses". Your regex says "Match a pair of parentheses surrounding a number", and you then need to extract the number from that. Both work the same in the end.

Comment: @TimPietzcker true, but isn't there a speed penalty with lookaround assertions?

Comment: The advantage is that you can use the same expression for searching and for replacing.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: I just timed it: The difference is negligible.

Answer (score 7):

A simpler regex is `\((\d+)\)`:

```
regex = re.compile(r'\((\d+)\)')
value = int(re.search(regex, fname).group(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd use this regex:

```
^.*\(\d+\)(?:\.[^().]+)?$
```

With this, I can pick the last number in parentheses, just before the extension (if any). It won't go and pick any random number in parentheses if there is any in the middle of the file name. For example, it should correctly pick out `2` from `SomeFilmTitle.(2012).RippedByGroup (2).avi`. The only drawback is that, it won't be able to differentiate when the number is right before the extension: `SomeFilmTitle (2012).avi`.

I make assumption that the extension of the file, if any, should not contain `()`.